# Netty - issues with GZIP in input stream

Tags: netty

I am trying to initiate a `Netty` channel using the following code

```
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ch.pipeline().addFirst(new ReadTimeoutHandler(30));
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new JdkZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new LineBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024));
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());

    }
```

The issue I am having is when I receive the data from a TCP stream

```
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException: Input is not in the GZIP format
    at io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.readGZIPHeader(JdkZlibDecoder.java:314) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.decode(JdkZlibDecoder.java:212) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[magic-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Is there something I am missing in the pipeline handlers which needs to be added/configured?

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct. Are you sure there is nothing that "prepend" the GZIP here ? I would use Wireshark to check what is on the wire.